# How to solve the warning problem and obtain real roots without imaginary part?

Tags: numerics, complex, precision-and-accuracy

I am trying to solve a equation with *Newton*'s method via `FindRoot`, and the codes are:

Define the functions:

```
τs[Ωs_,t_]:=2*Ωs*Coth[Ωs/(2*t)]
τb[Ωb_,t_]:=2*Ωb*Coth[Ωb/(2*t)]
Xs[Js_,Jb_,Ωs_,t_,δ_]:=(τs[Ωs,t]-4*Js-4*Js/(Sqrt[2])^δ)/(Jb+4*Js/(Sqrt[2])^δ+4*Js/(Sqrt[3])^δ)
Xb[Jb_,Ωb_,t_,δ_]:=(τb[Ωb,t]-4*Jb-4*Jb/(Sqrt[2])^δ)/(Jb+4*Jb/(Sqrt[2])^δ+4*Jb/(Sqrt[3])^δ)
ϕ[Jb_,Ωb_,t_,δ_]:=ArcCosh[Xb[Jb,Ωb,t,δ]/2]
BN[Jb_,Ωb_,t_,δ_,n_]:=Sinh[(n+1)*ϕ[Jb,Ωb,t,δ]]/Sinh[ϕ[Jb,Ωb,t,δ]]
fumfa[Js_,Jb_,Ωs_,Ωb_,t_,δ_,n_]:=(Xs[Js,Jb,Ωs,t,δ])^2*BN[Jb,Ωb,t,δ,n-2]-2*Xs[Js,Jb,Ωs,t,δ]*BN[Jb,Ωb,t,δ,n-3]+BN[Jb,Ωb,t,δ,n-4]
```

Solve a series of solutions:

```
Table[FindRoot[fumfa[2.0,1.0,Ωs,2.0,3.5,t,4]==0.0,{Ωs,4.0}],{t,0.1,4.0,0.2}]
```

However, I got the following warning message:

> The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than `MachinePrecision` digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

And some of the solutions have imaginary parts though the coefficients are actually zeros:

```
{{Ωs->11.6453 +0. I},{Ωs->10.5823 +0. I},{Ωs->9.58167 +0. I},{Ωs->8.63181 +0. I},{Ωs->7.72096 +0. I},{Ωs->6.83656 +0. I},{Ωs->5.96386 +0. I},{Ωs->5.08324 +0. I},{Ωs->4.16381 +0. I},{Ωs->3.14345 +0. I},{Ωs->1.82232},{Ωs->5.70687*10^-6},{Ωs->4.74748},{Ωs->3.29661},{Ωs->1.28711},{Ωs->-1.26412*10^-6},{Ωs->-3.05724*10^-6},{Ωs->-0.0000392875},{Ωs->0.0000453593},{Ωs->0.0000543535}}
```

My questions are:

1. How to remove the warning message?
2. why there are imaginary parts in the solutions and how to assure `Reals` only computation?

Comment: Do you want a "`Reals` only _computation_" or is removing the imaginary numbers afterwards acceptable?

Comment: `Re[]/.solutions` can remove imaginary parts easily; I am wondering how to compute via `reals` only method.

Comment: You can also use `Chop` to remove very small imaginaries caused by numerical methods applied to inexact numbers, which is your situation.

Comment: I am also curious about what causes the imaginary parts in the final solutions. Is that numerical errors? How can I use `reals` numerical computation via `FindRoot` then?

Comment: BTW for the first question, just use `Quiet@FindRoot[]`.

Comment: Often the warning message indicates that `FindRoot` got stuck at a non-root.  You should check your solutions to see if they are accurate enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have `t` in the slot for `δ` -- that may be a mistake.  Be that as it may, the the question about the warning `FindRoot::lstol` has an explanation.

Second, you're getting complex solutions because the function evaluates to complex numbers:

```
fumfa[2.0, 1.0, Ωs, 2.0, 3.5, t, 4] /. {t -> 0.1, Ωs -> 4.0}
(* 1.02171 + 0. I *)
```

Finally, the explanation.  The warning `FindRoot::lstol` means that *Mathematica* was having trouble making the function(s) close to zero.  This can happen at a local extremum, for instance.

We can use [`Check`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Check.html) to catch the values of `t` that produce warnings.  The value of `t` and the corresponding "solution" `sol0` will be stored in `err`. All solutions together with their corresponding values of `t` will be stored in `sol`.

```
Module[{sol0},
  err = {};
  sols = Table[
    Quiet@Check[
      sol0 = Flatten @
        {HoldPattern[t] -> t, FindRoot[fumfa[2.0, 1.0, Ωs, 2.0, 3.5, t, 4] == 0.0, {Ωs, 4.0}]},
      AppendTo[err, sol0]; sol0,
      {FindRoot::lstol}],
    {t, 0.1, 4.0, 0.2}]
  ];
```

Here are the values of `t` that produce warnings and the corresponding values of the function:

```
t /. err
fumfa[2.0, 1.0, Ωs, 2.0, 3.5, t, 4] /. err
(*
  {2.3, 3.1, 3.3, 3.5, 3.7, 3.9}
  {-0.0643143, 0.298996, 0.960447, 2.04808, 3.70264, 6.09244}
*)
```

You can have such large errors when the derivative of the objective function is very large, since $dy = f'(x)\;dx$.  That is not the case here:

```
D[fumfa[2.0, 1.0, Ωs, 2.0, 3.5, t, 4], Ωs] /. err
(* {-2.75827*10^-7, -1.67904*10^-7, -7.33596*10^-7, -0.0000152322, 0.0000266041, 0.0000460977} *)
```

In fact, we see that `FindMinimum` has gotten stuck at  relative extrema:

```
GraphicsGrid @ Partition[
  Hold[Plot[
      fumfa[2.0, 1.0, x, 2.0, 3.5, t, 4], {x, Ωs - 0.1, Ωs + 0.1}, 
      PlotLabel -> HoldForm["t" == t], 
      AxesLabel -> {"Ωs", "fumfa"}]] /. err // 
   ReleaseHold,
  3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]